# A continuous function $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ such that $f((0,1))=\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Question :
Propose a function $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb R$ such that $f$ is continous on $(0,1)$ and $range(f)=\mathbb R$.

My thoughts :

I've proved that $(0,1)$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$. But in that proof, i never proposed the function which takes something from $(0,1)$ and gives something in $\mathbb R$. I just proved that it exists. That's the problem ... I have no idea about how a function's range can span the whole $\mathbb R$.

Any solutions or even good hints would be nice from you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: start with $\tan$ and do some modifications

Comment: $\ln$ maps $(0,\infty)\longleftrightarrow \Bbb R$. So, pick something like $\ln\frac{x}{1-x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: the function
$$\tan : \left( -\tfrac{\pi}{2},\tfrac{\pi}{2} \right) \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \tan x$$
is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

You need a pole at $0$ and a pole at $1$. The simplest function providing these poles with the correct orientation is
$$
-\frac1x+\frac1{1-x}
$$